# Typeface error in log cat

Tags: android

I am writing the Persian app and i need to change the item of the list view from English to Persian but i got the type face error,i don't know what is the problem cause i follow the instructor.(i'm using android studio)
  this is the class

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends Activity {
public String fonts = "BZar.ttf";
@Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splashscreen);

    Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),  "font/" +fonts+"");
    TextView app_full_name=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.app_full_name);
    app_full_name.setTypeface(face);
    **String str_full_name = (String)  app_full_name.getText();
    app_full_name.setText(PersianReshape.reshape(str_full_name));**

       final int SplashScreenActivity_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 1000;


        Handler h = new Handler();
        h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            }
        }, SplashScreenActivity_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this , MainListActivity.class);


    startActivity(intent);}
}
```

activity_splashscreen.xml

```
 <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:id="@+id/app_logo"
 android:src="@drawable/app_logo"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:scaleType="centerInside"
 android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/app_full_name"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/app_full_name"
    android:textColorHint="#16a085"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/site_address"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/site_address"
    android:textColorHint="#16a085"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and i put the font folder in res.
  the error is
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
log cat:

```
        'at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.sali.package.MainListActivity.onCreate(MainListActivity.java:30)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
```

Comment: What is your error? Please post your error also .

Comment: @GrIsHu i edit the question with error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have put the font folder in the wrong directory, as you've stated in your question. Create a new folder called `assets` in the root of your project directory and place the fonts folder in there.

Comment: where should i create a assets folder in android studio

Comment: In the root of your project, under the src folder with the Java and res folder.

Comment: thanks,but now i have null pointer exception error.does it relate to this part of the code,i have the class of PersianReshape that include persian codes.   ' String str_full_name = (String)  app_full_name.getText();
    app_full_name.setText(PersianReshape.reshape(str_full_name));'

Comment: What line does the logcat say its on? Update the question with the logcat and the line of code highlighted

Comment: Can't you just add Persian version of the test to your strings.XML? And fetch it from there? Because this won't translate the text

Comment: i do it but got the error again,it even doesn't show its splash screen :(